# Upgrade thousand for mysql 5.7 databases to latest 8.0 version

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0, mysqlupgrade

We are having thousands of mysql databases (v 5.7) and want to upgrade to latest v8.0. We have configured new mysql on same sarver with diff port (say 3307).
we tried multiple steps

1. Replacing mysql5.7/data directory to mysql8.0/data gives an error on service start (attached error.log from mysql)

   2019-08-08T10:44:03.134490-00:00 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.

   2019-08-08T10:46:14.363244-00:00 1 [ERROR] [MY-012083] [InnoDB] Table mysql/plugin is not found in InnoDB dictionary

We checked mysql/plugin table on older version, table is listed in "show tables" command but gives an error on executing "desc plugin" as table not found.

2. on new mysql 8.0 we started the service, stopped it again. Moved only databases folder mysql5.7/data directory to mysql8.0/data. but service couldn't started at this time.

Can some one guide me to upgrade thousands of dbs (volume 300+gb) to latest version in one go.. export/ import will take more time. Is there any alternate way?

Comment: Have you read this https://mysqlserverteam.com/inplace-upgrade-from-mysql-5-7-to-mysql-8-0/ and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading.html

Comment: There are BIG changes in the meta data handling between 5.7 and 8.0 and you will be unhappy without following the upgrade documents. And you can not as of now downgrade from 8.0 to 5.7 due to those changes.   With 8.0.17 you no longer have to run the upgrade script as it runs automatically but you will need those updates.  And you might want to look at the upgrade checker in the new MySQL Shell.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes I did it. With INPLACE upgrade process, up-gradation completed with error (tablespace id already exist which resolved by removing *.idb files ) but now it is showing 0kb information schema, and databases are not listed.